# how can I display multiple category lists in one article in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

How can I display a category list and the articles that belong to them, as a tree structure, displaying only the names of the articles and categories?

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: it is 3 but a guide for 2.5 should do as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to the Module Manager and open the module called "Articles Category". In there you can edit the parameter to suit your needs and this will display a tree structure of categories and the articles that belong to them.

If you want to display this module inside an article then give the module a custom position by typing one in, instead of selecting one. The in the article, add the following code:

```
{loadposition xxx}
```

Change **xxx** to the name if your custom position.

Comment: But I want to display articles in those Categories

Comment: so you want a list of all categories and articles within those categories? Might be an idea to add a little more detail to your question so I fully understand ;)

Comment: Yes. I want to display name of category as title of the list of articles in that category, and I want to display 3 of these lists

Comment: @TasawerKhan - See my updated answer. I think this is what you're looking for