# How to list all article from selected cetagory with title, exerpt and read more link in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I want to display all article from selected cetagory with title, exerpt and read more link in joomla

Thanks

Comment: too worst post. make your question more constructive, if you need helpful answer.

Comment: I think you need this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435872/how-can-i-display-multiple-category-lists-in-one-article-in-joomla/13435909#13435909

Answer (score 0):

check the demo and download this extension.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/news-tickers-a-scrollers/11827